# Why do I get NULL results with the MySQL function TIME_TO_SEC?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a MySQL table with two datetime columns. I want to create one new generated column that contains time difference of the two datetime columns. I am using the MySQL function `TIME_TO_SEC` to convert the difference to seconds.

Strangely some of the rows return a NULL, and I am unable to understand why.
Here are the first 25 rows of the table..

```
 class_session_id starts_on           ends_on              session_time_computed
                8 2014-12-24 03:35:47 2014-12-24 05:07:33                    NA
                9 2014-12-24 05:50:37 2014-12-24 07:10:07                    NA
               10 2014-12-24 07:18:51 2014-12-24 08:52:27                    NA
               11 2014-12-19 09:00:41 2014-12-19 10:35:54                  5713
               12 2014-12-19 10:45:29 2014-12-19 11:55:48                  4219
               13 2014-12-24 12:00:00 2014-12-24 14:00:00                  7200
               14 2014-12-24 14:32:10 2014-12-24 14:47:18                   908
               15 2014-12-24 14:48:13 2014-12-25 08:29:51                    NA
               16 2014-12-15 04:06:13 2014-12-15 04:20:41                   868
               17 2014-12-15 07:09:27 2014-12-15 08:20:40                  4273
               18 2014-12-15 06:42:28 2014-12-15 06:51:43                   555
               28 2014-11-25 11:18:00 2014-11-25 09:30:00                    NA
               29 2014-11-27 10:18:00 2014-11-27 11:30:00                  4320
               30 2014-11-26 08:18:00 2014-11-26 09:30:00                  4320
               34 2015-01-08 10:41:52 2015-01-08 11:00:00                  3528
               37 2014-12-02 12:44:36 2014-12-02 14:44:00                    NA
               49 2014-11-02 12:44:00 2014-11-02 14:44:00                  7200
               54 2014-12-07 07:05:35 2014-12-07 07:50:00                    NA
               55 2014-12-07 10:00:00 2014-12-07 11:00:00                  3600
               56 2014-11-12 12:57:00 2014-11-12 17:00:00                 16980
               82 2014-12-05 14:29:18 2014-12-05 16:00:00                    NA
               83 2014-12-05 16:29:18 2014-12-05 17:00:00                    NA
               84 2014-12-05 17:49:17 2014-12-05 18:25:00                    NA
               85 2014-12-06 15:00:17 2014-12-06 16:00:00                    NA
               87 2014-12-06 16:25:00 2014-12-06 16:59:00                  2040`
```

I use the following script to generate the last column.

```
 ALTER TABLE class_sessions_archive
        MODIFY COLUMN session_time_computed int(11) AS (TIME_TO_SEC(ends_on - starts_on));
```

Why do I get NULL results for so many rows?
Here is the structure of the table :

```
           Field     Type Null Key Default             Extra
      class_session_id  int(11)   NO PRI    <NA>    auto_increment
              class_id  int(11)   NO MUL    <NA>                  
               room_id  int(11)   NO MUL    <NA>                  
            teacher_id  int(11)   NO MUL    <NA>                  
             starts_on datetime   NO        <NA>                  
               ends_on datetime   NO        <NA>                  
         session_state  int(11)   NO MUL    <NA>                  
         stud_attended int(100)  YES        <NA>                  
 total_stud_registered  int(11)   NO           0                  
          session_time  int(11)   NO           0                  
                gi_num  int(11)   NO           0                  
                gi_den  int(11)   NO           0                  
                    pi  int(11)   NO           0                  
 session_time_computed  int(11)  YES        <NA> VIRTUAL GENERATED
```

Comment: Try: `... AS TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, starts_on, ends_on);`.

Comment: This is more compact @wchiquito. Although both your solutions run in a SELECT command format but fail in the ALTER TABLE format.:
This works:
 `"SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, starts_on, ends_on) as x, TO_SECONDS(ends_on)-TO_SECONDS(starts_on) as y from class_sessions_archive LIMIT 300`

But this does not: 
`ALTER TABLE class_sessions_archive
        MODIFY COLUMN session_time_computed int(11) AS
            (TO_SECONDS(ends_on) - TO_SECONDS(starts_on));`
Gives error:
 `Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : 
  could not run statement: Truncated incorrect time value: '17186' `

Comment: With some test data I can't reproduce the problem, see [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/s6vHMqKdsbFRSFRmWNTUiZ/1). @GordonLinoff.

Answer (score 1):

Now that I think about it, you normally convert the time to seconds *before* subtracting:

```
ALTER TABLE class_sessions_archive
        MODIFY COLUMN session_time_computed int(11) AS
            (TO_SECONDS(ends_on) - TO_SECONDS(starts_on));
```

Otherwise, you are limited by the range of values for the `time` data type -- which is probably why you are getting `NULL`.

Comment: [TIME_TO_SEC](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec) function doesn't include the date, so the result may not be as expected. [TIMESTAMPDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) function seems appropriate in this case. See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/r8xT64gbdXJoEmFb8k6yFD/0).

Comment: @wchiquito . . . Good catch.  That should be `TO_SECONDS()`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: please read my comments  in reply to wchiquito